# Redux Error: Application state or actions payloads are too large - what is the issue?

Tags: redux, websocket, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, createentityadapter

`VM75:3075 Application state or actions payloads are too large making Redux DevTools serialization slow and consuming a lot of memory. See https://git.io/fpcP5 on how to configure it.`

I am getting the error above when working with Redux Toolkit RTK Query and Entity Adapters.

I am getting data from the query and use setAll to normalise the data. I am also getting the data from websocket and updating the nomalise data with the new data. I am Json parsing it before.

I am looking to find out what the issue is. Is the action payload too large? The list of items is not that big so Its probably not.

Any help would be appreciated.